# Failure to boot after running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, hard-disk, io, system-recovery

I just recently ran a bash script that froze up my Linux mint machine, and I had no choice but to hold power key to perform a hard power off.

Now my machine will not boot.

I have no clue if the bash script did something, the hard reset did something, or it is just coincidence and my harddrive died.

I created a bash script as follows

```
for file in 4k/*
do
  convert $file -resize 50% 1080p/$file
done
```

I ran in the folder ~/Pictures/EastTrip/Finals/

When I ran this script the UI started to become unresponsive. Then I performed the hard reset.

At the same time I ran the script that was working on directory "4k", I had the program rawtherapee writing to the directory 4k. I can't help but feel like the file system is broke and not the harddrive.

I have entered recovery mode and dropped down to root shell. When I navigate to the Pictures directory and use ls command I get the following errors....

[image]

What have I done?!?! I have like a weeks of unsaved work :/

Comment: Looks like your hard drive may be failing.  I don't think your script necessarily _caused_ it although if it was performing a lot of processing on many large files it may have been enough strain to push it over the edge.

Comment: @Jesse_b your comment seems the right answer to me.

Comment: I see no reason to close this. Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with "READ DMA" and "I/O error" are not problems with scripts, applications or the filesystem, but problems with the actual harddrive.

To answer your question: nothing in particular, but your harddrive is failing.

I can recommend turning the failing drive off for now, and later take a copy of whatever can be copied to a harddrive that is not failing.